# Codeigniter 'is_unique' validations with sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I have to do validations in codeigniter against db. I use sql server and my tables have the syntax `[db].[dbo].[table]` (I use many dbs). The question is if is possible to made a is_unique validation like:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('login', 'login', 'required|trim|xss_clean|is_unique[auditorias].[dbo].[usuarios].login]');
```

I have an error that consider a query against auditorias database with `dbo` column to be unique. In codeigniter documentation the syntax is `table.column`, but it seems not to have `db.dbo.table.column`.

Is there any method to do this without callback functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just see that there isn't any method, so I did it with a callback_ function.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('login', 'login', 'required|trim|xss_clean|is_unique[auditorias.login]|is_unique[dbo.login]|is_unique[usuarios.login]');
```

Comment: I have the same error: SELECT TOP 1 * FROM auditorias WHERE login = 'name' it don't recognise the full db.dbo.table path.

Comment: can you explain your table structure

Comment: I have many tables; [auditorias].[dbo].[usuarios], [auditorias].[dbo].[auditores] and others in the same proyect, so I don´t have only one db and table and I have to access to name column of usuarios table of auditorías db for this validation.